# How can I display a second and third button on my React App after the previews one has already been clicked?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

I'm currently building a CSV file loader which parses the data into a JSON, It will have three different buttons, the first one which is the one that let me pick a file from my computer and loads the CSV data to convert it to JSON, after that I need to display a second button that will allow me to connect to a Shopify API, when this button is clicked it will make a get request to the API to get the JSON data and match the ID's with the file I uploaded, after that happens it will store all those ID's that match and here is when the Third button has to be displayed, this is the last button that needs to make a POST request to another API. I only need to know the button functionality, like, how can I display one, store the data and display the next one and so on.

Since I'm new into coding, I'm kind of lost right now, I've been thinking of setting the state for this and hide the buttons (second and third), the thing is that I don't know how to make a button displayed after data is loaded and not just when the button is clicked.

I'm using the react-file-reader NPM module to make the render from CSV to JSON.

```
`export default class csvLoader extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
 }
 handleFiles = files => {
   let reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(e) {
     // Use reader.result
     let csv = reader.result;
     let lines = csv.split("\n");
     let result = [];
     let headers = lines[0].split(",");
     for (let i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
       let obj = {};
       let currentLine = lines[i].split(",");
       for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
      obj[headers[j]] = currentLine[j];
     }
     result.push(obj);
    }
  //return result; //JavaScript object
  result = JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
  console.log(result);
 };
 reader.readAsText(files[0]);
 };
 render() {
   return (
      <ReactFileReader handleFiles={this.handleFiles} fileTypes=".csv"}>
         <button className="btn btn-primary">Importar CSV</button>
      </ReactFileReader>
    );
  }
}`
```

There are no error messages, all data is being displayed in the console, Info doesn't have to be displayed on the console, but stored to be compared with the other API's information.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best solution would be to create an action for your api call pass your data to redux and make sure that your component is listening for changes for that particular data entity in store, assuming you're using redux. If not then handling the status of your buttons via the component state would be optimal as well.